# How can I use the data retrieved from Google Analytics and show it in Google Charts

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, google-visualization

I have performed all the query functionality where the account gets authenticated first and then get the queried result from Google Analytics.

I output the result in a table code is below;

```
//To Get the Profile ID first
function queryCoreReportingApi(profileId) {
  updatePage('Querying Core Reporting API.');
  gapi.client.analytics.data.ga.get({
    'ids': 'ga:' + profileId,
    'start-date': lastNDays(14),
    'end-date': lastNDays(0),
    'dimensions': 'ga:date,ga:year,ga:month,ga:week,ga:day',
    'metrics': 'ga:visitors'

  }).execute(handleCoreReportingResults);
}

//To Show the Result

function handleCoreReportingResults(response) {
  if (!response.code) {
    if (response.rows && response.rows.length) {
      var output = [];

      // Profile Name.
      output.push('Profile Name: ', response.profileInfo.profileName, '<br>'); 

      var table = ['<table>'];

      // Put headers in table.
      table.push('<tr>');
      for (var i = 0, header; header = response.columnHeaders[i]; ++i) {
        table.push('<th>', header.name, '</th>');
      }
      table.push('</tr>');

      // Put cells in table.
      for (var i = 0, row; row = response.rows[i]; ++i) {
        table.push('<tr><td>', row.join('</td><td>'), '</td></tr>');
      }
      table.push('</table>');

      output.push(table.join(''));
      outputToPage(output.join(''));
    } else {
      outputToPage('No results found.');
    }
  } else {
    updatePage('There was an error querying core reporting API: ' +
        response.message);
  }
}

function outputToPage(output) {
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = output;
}



function updatePage(output) {
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += '<br>' + output;
```

}

Now the problem is how can I this returned result and show it in google charts (bars charts - pie charts etc).
I tired to use googlecharts.js but not user how to integrate. Can anyone help please

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, the [Getting Started](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/quick_start) guide should be exactly what you need. I'll summarize here, but I might leave out some subtleties you need to do:

1. Include JSAPI: `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>`
2. Load the library: `<script type="text/javascript">google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});</script>`
3. Add a callback: `google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);`
4. Draw your charts in the `drawChart` function.

Then, I would go, and look at the documentation on the individual charts, and fill in the details. As you are already displaying your data as a table, I'd start with [Google's Table Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table), and move on from there.

Comment: Still can't find how to put the data in chart like I am doing in table

Comment: You just want to put it in a 2D JS array, rather than the table. For example, on your `row.join('xxx')`, change it to `row.join('],[')`, and then you need the beginning and end, but it shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: I tried this
`var result = '';
   for(var i=0; i<response.rows.length; i++) {
      result += '["'+response.rows[i]+'"],';
    }
      result = result.substring(0, result.length - 1);
        data.addRows(result);`
And it gives me this error  _Error: Argument given to addRows must be either a number or an array_ @jeremy Faller

Comment: This should be easy to debug if you look in the console output. Look at the variable `response` and see what the value is. You likely haven't formatted it correctly.

Comment: `console.dir(response);`
gives me object.